# Files have disappeared in Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been working in VS2010 for years ... working on a web site at the moment, suddenly the Solution Explorer is empty. It shows at the top C:\Development\MyWebSite\ but no files or folders are showing below.

I have tried Refresh Folder but nothing changes.

How can I get the files and folders to reappear?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing happen.  I simply closed the solution, opened a previously worked-on solution; closed that solution; reopened the original and all of the files were now again displayed in Solution Explorer.